# Insert into table based on rows in same table

Tags: sql, join, sybase, sql-insert, self-join

I have a table as per below which will contain multiple rows of data - a couple of thousand rows max.

```
lvl2  | lvl3 | lvl6 | this_rep_cycle   | last_rep_cycle | prev_rep_cycle | rowType
================================================================================
ASSET | CURR | FI   | 214,060,924,928  | 0              | 0              | 1-Total
ASSET | CURR | FI   | 25,199,630,336   | 0              | 0              | 3-Bal
ASSET | CURR | FX   | 123,941,472      | 0              | 0              | 1-Total
ASSET | CURR | FX   | 0                | 0              | 0              | 3-Bal
```

What I need to to is inset a new row in the table with the same lv12, vl3, lvl6, but where:

```
this_rep_cycle = (this_rep_cycle for rowType = '3-Bal' / this_rep_cycle for rowType = '1-total)
last_rep_cycle = (last_rep_cycle for rowType = '3-Bal' / last_rep_cycle for rowType = '1-total)
prev_rep_cycle = (prev_rep_cycle for rowType = '3-Bal' / prev_rep_cycle for rowType = '1-total)
```

The end result should look like:

```
lvl2  | lvl3 | lvl6 | this_rep_cycle   | last_rep_cycle | prev_rep_cycle | rowType
================================================================================
ASSET | CURR | FI   | 214,060,924,928  | 0              | 0              | 1-Total
ASSET | CURR | FI   | 25,199,630,336   | 0              | 0              | 3-Bal
ASSET | CURR | FI   | 11.77            | 0              | 0              | 4-%
ASSET | CURR | FX   | 123,941,472      | 0              | 0              | 1-Total
ASSET | CURR | FX   | 0                | 0              | 0              | 3-Bal
ASSET | CURR | FX   | 0                | 0              | 0              | 4-%
```

I have written a self join to achieve this:

```
set arithignore on
select  
pd_1.lvl2, pd_1.lvl3, pd_1.lvl4, pd_1.lvl6, pd_2.last_report_cycle as p2_lrp, pd_1.last_report_cycle  as p1_lrp,
    (pd_2.this_report_cycle / pd_1.this_report_cycle)*100 as this_report_cycle,
    (pd_2.last_report_cycle / pd_1.last_report_cycle)*100 as last_report_cycle 
--  (pd_2.prev_report_cycle / pd_1.prev_report_cycle)*100 as prev_report_cycle,     
--  '4-%' as [percentage]
from ProxyTrending pd_1
    inner join ProxyTrending pd_2 on pd_2.rowType = '3-Bal'
        AND pd_1.lvl2 = pd_2.lvl2
        AND pd_1.lvl3 = pd_2.lvl3
        AND pd_1.lvl4 = pd_2.lvl4
        AND pd_1.lvl6 = pd_2.lvl6
where pd_1.rowType = '1-Total'
    --order by pd_1.lvl2, pd_1.lvl3, pd_1.lvl4, pd_1.lvl6
set arithignore off
```

I need `set arithignore` as I can experience div/zero, but when i execute the above, it (partially) works if only one of the `(report_cycle / report_cycle)*100` is uncommented - 2 or more of these lines and zero results are returned.

also, if i have just one of the `(report_cycle / report_cycle)*100` uncommented, 60 results are returned where there are 106 '1-total' records and 106 '3-Bal' records - I would have expected the proc to run and return 106 '4-%' results.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i have the cause of the error.  If I execute:

```
select pd_2.this_report_cycle, pd_1.this_report_cycle...
```

the statement executes and returns values.  If I place:

```
select pd_2.this_report_cycle, pd_1.this_report_cycle,  
       (pd_2.this_report_cycle / pd_1.this_report_cycle)*100 as expected_result
```

the query return zero rows if either of the values are 0, despite the ARITHIGNORE setting.

And  the CASE statement solves the issue.